# how to find shadow-root element in Chrome using Atata lib

Tags: selenium, atata

So I have an element in the DOM [this is how it actually looks in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gh8L.png)

I was trying to locate it like this

```
[FindById("someId"), As = FindAs.ShadowHost, Visibility = Visibility.Any]
public Text<_> SomeElement {get; private set;}
```

And I get an error, originally thrown from Selenium:

```
OpenQa.Selenium.WebDriverException: javascript error: Cannot read property 'children' of null
```